# MVC Redirect to View from jQuery with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have seen some posts relating to this but can't seem to get it to work. With the redirect I get a 'resource cannot be found error'.

I am trying to redirect to a Details page. There is an ID in element which I store as NestId that I want to eventually be able to pass to the View. Right now I just want to redirect to the details page, there isn't a model or anything attached to it. I just want the NestId to make it there so that I can use it to make more AJAX calls with it.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#results').on('click', '.item', function () {
            var NestId = $(this).data('id');
            var url = '@Url.Action("Details, Artists")'; 
            window.location.href = url; 
        })
```

Here is the function on the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string NestId)
    {
        ViewBag.NestId = NestId; 
        return View();
    }
```

I'm not sure if I am going about this the right way but help would be appreciated, I've stalled on this for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If your click handler is successfully called then this should work:

```
$('#results').on('click', '.item', function () {
            var NestId = $(this).data('id');
            var url = "/Artists/Details?NestId=" + NestId; 
            window.location.href = url; 
        })
```

EDIT: In this particular case given that the action method parameter is a string which is *nullable*, then if `NestId == null`, won't cause any exception at all, given that the ModelBinder won't complain about it.

Comment: This does seem to get the job done. Is there a way around hard coding the url like that?

Comment: You could just replace it by: @Url.Action("Details", "Artists",new { NestId = '+NestId+'  })' as @ABs suggests. Also, consider accepting the answer that helped you in order to help others.

Comment: Yea, I was waiting to see if there was a solution that didn't hard code it. When I tried the option you and ABs said, I get an error (I commented on his below).

Answer (score 5):

> i used to do like this
>
> inside **view**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//will replace the '_transactionIds_' and '_payeeId_' 
var _addInvoiceUrl = '@(Html.Raw( Url.Action("PayableInvoiceMainEditor", "Payables", new { warehouseTransactionIds ="_transactionIds_",payeeId = "_payeeId_", payeeType="Vendor" })))';
```

> on **javascript** file

```
var url = _addInvoiceUrl.replace('_transactionIds_', warehouseTransactionIds).replace('_payeeId_', payeeId);
        window.location.href = url;
```

> in this way i can able to pass the parameter values on demand..
>
> by using @Html.Raw,  url will not get **amp;** for parameters

Comment: I like this solution, very clean! :)

Answer (score 0):

This would also work I believe:

```
$('#results').on('click', '.item', function () {
            var NestId = $(this).data('id');
            var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Artists", new { NestId = @NestId }))';
            window.location.href = url; 
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

redirect with query string

```
 $('#results').on('click', '.item', function () {
                    var NestId = $(this).data('id');
                   // var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Artists",new { NestId = '+NestId+'  })'; 
                    var url = '@ Url.Content("~/Artists/Details?NestId =' + NestId + '")'
                    window.location.href = url; 
                })
```

Comment: I get an error around the NestId saying there is too many characters in character literal on the url...

Comment: you may try this, var url = '@ Url.Content("~/Artists/Details?NestId =' + NestId + '")'